# toggle sidenav from another component in angular

Tags: angular, header, components, toggle, sidenav

I want to toggle a sidenav from another component in Angular. I have 3 child Components: **menu,content,header**. Button is on header component.I want to click on button then menu should toggle.

**header.ts**

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public service: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleMenu() {
    this.service.flag = !this.service.flag;
    this.service.flagChange.emit(this.service.flag);
  }
}
```

**header.html**

```html
<div>
  <a href="">
    <i class="fas fa-bars text-white barsIcon" ` (click)="toggleMenu()"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**menu.ts**

```js
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public service: SharedService) {
    this.service.flagChange.subscribe((res) => this.service.flag);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**menu.html**

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/user">User</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a routerLink="">Currency</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/report">Report</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class SharedService {
  public flag: boolean = false;
  public flagChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share stackblitz with working example to check what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't that fare, but you should use `BehaviorSubject` and not `EventEmitter` for that purpose
*Emitter a meant for @Output()*

here some little changes.
*I also refactor a little bit your code ;)*

**header.ts**

```js
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {}
}
```

**header.html**

```html
<div>
  <a href="">
    <i class="fas fa-bars text-white barsIcon" (click)="sharedService.toggleMenu()"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**menu.ts**

```js
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  protected _unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  flag?: boolean

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.onFlagChange$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.flag = value
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribe$.next();
    this._unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

**menu.html**

```html
<div [class.hidden]="!flag"> <!-- or *ngIf, as you wish ;) -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/user">User</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a routerLink="">Currency</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/report">Report</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="">Report3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class SharedService {
  flag = false;
  onFlagChange$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(this.flag);

  constructor() {}

  toggleMenu() {
    this.flag = !this.flag;
    this.onFlagChange$.next(this.flag); // Here, .next instead of .emit
  }
}
```

#### Error

1. Using `BehaviorSubject` instead of `EventEmitter`

#### Optimization

1. Always unsubscribe from observable!

#### Refactoring

1. Do not declare `:boolean` if you're already adding a value to it, this is implicit.
2. Move toggle logic inside the `service`
3. Do not declare `ngOnInit` if not used
4. Make services `private` if not used in the `html` file

Comment: thanks for your response, but it doesn't work

Comment: thanks but it has an error.it doesn't know flagChange

Comment: @nafise You're right, silly me. I've updated my answer & added a new point `4` for refactoring Ideas. Please tell me if it now works

Comment: sorry but, it doesn't work

Comment: Could you prepare the code in a stackblitz ? I'll be glad to see where errors may still be. I do not have the code, therefore it's hard to code with 100% certitude